# Missing argument 2

Tags: functions

Hi just looking for help with this cant solve this

Thanks

Missing argument 2 for t2t_homepage_slide()XXXXXXX/index.php on line 41 and defined in/xxxxxxx/ten.php on line 94

```
<?php
                    $slide1 = get_option($shortname.'_slide_1'); 
                    $slide2 = get_option($shortname.'_slide_2'); 
                    $slide3 = get_option($shortname.'_slide_3'); 
                    $slide4 = get_option($shortname.'_slide_4'); 
                    $slide5 = get_option($shortname.'_slide_5'); 
                ?>
                <?php if($slide1 != '') : ?>
                    <?php t2t_homepage_slide($shortname.'_slide_1'); ?>   <--line 41
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($slide2 != '') : ?>
                    <?php t2t_homepage_slide($shortname.'_slide_2'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($slide3 != '') : ?>
                    <?php t2t_homepage_slide($shortname.'_slide_3'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($slide4 != '') : ?>
                    <?php t2t_homepage_slide($shortname.'_slide_4'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($slide5 != '') : ?>
                    <?php t2t_homepage_slide($shortname.'_slide_5'); ?>
```

```
function t2t_homepage_slide($slide,$size) {     <--- line 94
    global $wpdb;

    $image = get_option($slide);
    $caption = get_option($slide.'_caption');
    $price = get_option($slide.'_price');
    $url = get_option($slide.'_url');
```

Answer (score 1):

You `t2t_homepage_slide($slide,$size)` function requires 2 arguments and your only calling it with one.

Either include the $size argument when calling the function or remove the requirement or provide a default when defining the function (line 94).  eg:

```
function t2t_homepage_slide( $slide, $size = '') {     <--- line 94
    global $wpdb;

    $image = get_option($slide);
    $caption = get_option($slide.'_caption');
    $price = get_option($slide.'_price');
    $url = get_option($slide.'_url');
```

Also since this is a commercial theme you should be able to get the support you need from the [themes support forum](http://themes.two2twelve.com/support/).